# oracle - how to remove table dependents without on delete cascade

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the following oracle tables:

```
Family= { pk_id_family, nm_family } 
Generation_1 = { pk_id_gen_1, nm_gen_1, fk_id_family} 
Dependent_gen_1 = { pk_id_dep_gen_1, nm_dep_gen_1, fk_id_gen_1 }
Dependent_gen_2 = { pk_id_dep_gen_2, nm_dep_gen_2, fk_id_dep_gen_1 }
Acquainted = {pk_id_acquainted, nm_acquainted, fk_id_gen_1 }
```

I wanna create a procedure that receives **pk_id_family** for parameter and deletes recursively in **Generation_1** and after deletes from **Generation_1** (using  **fk_id_family**) goes on deleting from **Dependent_gen_2** (using **fk_id_dep_gen_1**) and so on until **Acquainted**.

Note: I could do it **activating DELETE CASCADE on the constraints**, but **I would like to know if there is another way to do that**.

Trigger is not an option because I don't want to change the tables behavior. The procedure wouldn't be used often. **I don't want to change the tables behavior using triggers.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure for Oracle but you can do this with trigger on delete.
You can find more on triggers in this link.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch15.htm

Comment: That's correct, but my goal is to make a procedure that could centralize all the deletions.  I don't wanna touch on the schema behavior.  If I use trigger the tables will always behave on that way and besides it would spread the code all around (hard to mantain). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could delete the data using joins up the family tree, but that would be horrible code, something like

```
DELETE FROM Acquainted 
 WHERE fk_id_gen_1 IN 
       (SELECT fk_id_gen_1 
          FROM Dependent_gen_1 
          JOIN Generation_1    ON fk_id_gen_1=pk_id_gen1
         WHERE fk_id_family= my_parameter);

DELETE FROM Dependent_gen_2 
 WHERE fk_id_dep_gen_1 IN 
       (SELECT pk_id_dep_gen_1 
          FROM Dependent_gen_1 
          JOIN Generation_1    ON fk_id_gen_1=pk_id_gen1
         WHERE fk_id_family= my_parameter);
```

and so on...

Comment: Yes, this is a way, but I would take a lot of work. I was looking for some oracle function or directive that could help me do it in a procedure.  Thanks for your help